# How to write a 3D numpy array to a 1D std::vector in C++ using boost::python?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, boost, boost-python

I am writing a python extension using boost::python and I would like to have a function that takes a 3D numpy array as an argument (this cannot be changed). Internally however, I use functions that take 1D std::vectors and column major ordering (x incrementing the fastest, z the slowest).

So the function would have the following signature I guess:

```
void takeNumpyArray(boost::python::numeric::array& array)
{
    std::vector<float> vec;

    // Make sure the array stores floats
    // Find out dimensions of array (make sure it's 3)
    vec.reserve(xmax*ymax*zmax);  
    for(size_t x=0; x<xmax; ++x)
        for(size_t y=0; y<ymax; ++y)
            for(size_t z=0; z<zmax; ++z)
                vec[x+xmax*(y+ymax*z)] = array[std::make_tuple(x,y,z)];

    std::cout << "Success!";
}
```

So there are some things I didn't find in the documentation (like dimensions and element type).

**Question:** How do I copy a 3D numpy array into a std::vector using boost::python?

**Bonus**: Is there a way to do it without manual indexing (using some flattening options of numpy array followed by a simple iterator begin/end copy or so?)

Comment: have you looked into Cython? It could help you out wrapping the C++ code and interfacing with NumPy arrays

Comment: I have already done quite some work with boost python and would not like to switch at this stage. Also while the overview page of the documentation does mention C++ the tutorial section only talkes about C.

Comment: Have a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38886567/4899330). It may not be exactly what you are looking for but may be a good starting point for further investigation.